# Within an Event Trigger, how can I modify related Opportunity fields?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, event

I have a trigger that is supposed to check if an Event picklist value is a certain value, and if it is, to change a field in its related Opportunity.

I was able to pull the Opportunity's id with event.whatid, but I need to get the actual Opportunity to get its field information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the trigger code you have created.

Answer (score 1):

You trigger on event needs to be bulkified. So the logic would be

1. Iterate through trigger.new of events in the event trigger
2. Add the WhatId field to a set of IDs- OppIDSet(Add it only if it is an opportunity ID, check this by comparing the first the letters of WhatID to key prefix of opportunity)
3. SOQL - Query all the opportunity(with required fields) WHERE Id IN OppIDSet
4. Now you have a list of opportunity from the above query. Using a for loop iterate through each opportunity and make the required changes in the field values.
5. Update the list of opportunity records.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List<Id>` while iterating over your Event list. Then query the opportunities with those ids, iterate over the retrieved opportunities changing their status, and finally update them.

Answer (score 0):

An event can have 'n' number of related objects. You can determine if the related object is an opportunity by using the following piece of code in your trigger entry condition.

```
for (Event ev : Trigger.new) {
    if (ev.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Schema.Opportunity.sobjectType) {
       if (picklist change) 
           //grab opportunity Id and pick list change into a map<Id, String>
             xMap.put(ev.whatId, ev.picklist);
    }
}
```

query the opportunities based on xMap.keyset() and store in a list. Finally Iterate through the list to make necessary changes using xmap.